# Auto click event, simulating a users click

Tags: php, jquery, events, click

```
if ($amLanguage['id'] == AM_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_ID){
?>
&nbsp;<input id="default_language" type="image" src="<?php echo DIR_WS_CATALOG_LANGUAGES . $amLanguage['directory'] . '/images/' . $amLanguage['image'];?>" title="<?php echo AM_AJAX_CHANGES;?>" 
<?php echo 'onclick="return amSetInterfaceLanguage(\''.AM_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_ID.'\');"';?> >
<?php
}else{....
```

And I have:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    function language_def() {
    $('type#default_language').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

The purpose is to trigger the click event, simulating a users click, for the id="default_language"

I have been trying for days, but nothin works...:(

Somebody plz

Sara

Comment: $("element").click(); will simulate a click. // También funciona .change() .submit() para sus respectivos...

Answer (score 1):

You put the `trigger` code in a function. Either call it or Remove the function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myObject').click()
});
```

Also, everything before the `#` id selector is irrelevant and just wastes bits.

Comment: Hi, I corrected my snippet so now I do not have any errors. But, nothing happens, no "auto click". Could it be this line?              <?php echo 'onclick="return amSetInterfaceLanguage(\''.AM_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_ID.'\');"';?>

Comment: do you use firebug? do you have any errors? sometimes syntax or some errors may cause javascript to malfunction.

Comment: Yes I am using firefox/firebug as it is now, there's no errors: 
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#default_language').trigger('click');
});


if ($amLanguage['id'] == AM_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_ID){
   ?>
   &nbsp;<input id="default_language" type="image" src="<?php echo DIR_WS_CATALOG_LANGUAGES . $amLanguage['directory'] . '/images/' . $amLanguage['image'];?>" title="<?php echo AM_AJAX_CHANGES;?>" 
      onclick="return amSetInterfaceLanguage(\''.$amLanguage['id'].'\')" >
   <?php
}else...

Answer (score 0):

This won't work?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    function language_def() {
    $('type#default_language').click();
    }
});
```

Actually, why do you need the function `language_def`? Simply doing this may work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('type#default_language').click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I have tried the suggested solutions:

$(document).ready(function() {

$('type#default_language').('click');

});

and got this error:

XML filter is applied to non-XML value ({length:0, prevObject:{0:#4=({}), context:#4#, length:1}, context:#4#, selector:"type#default_language"})
So, next step?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Have you managed to get the jQuery's `$(document).ready(function() { });` function set up?